# mssql_query returns nothing

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My app uses PHP 5.5 and MS SQL to query some records from database and displays. This query takes around 2 minutes to execute when run on the SQL server.

My issue is that `mssql_query()` returns NOTHING sometimes (i.e. neither resource id nor true or false).

I have a hunch that the issue is caused due to MS SQL timeout, but I am failing to prove it as I have `mssql.timeout = 300` (sec) configured in php.ini file.

Can anyone help me in finding the root cause please? I am new to php.

SQL query:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

SELECT 
    *
FROM table1 latest
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 successful 
ON latest.MachineVersionID = successful.MachineVersionID
 AND successful.BackupToken = (
    SELECT TOP 1 BackupToken
    FROM table1
    WHERE MachineVersionID = successful.MachineVersionID
    AND BackupState = 7 AND IsPartial = 0
    ORDER BY EndTime DESC
)
INNER JOIN table2 mv ON latest.MachineVersionID = mv.MachineVersionID
INNER JOIN table3 m ON mv.MachineID = m.MachineID
INNER JOIN table4 c ON m.ClientID = c.ClientID
WHERE latest.BackupToken = (
    SELECT TOP 1 BackupToken
    FROM table1
    WHERE MachineVersionID = latest.MachineVersionID
    ORDER BY EndTime DESC
)
AND c.PartnerID in (1,2,3,4,5,....)
ORDER BY latest.MachineVersionID
```

Comment: What is the query? Can you post it here?

Comment: @asha please post your code here so that all can help you easily and faster

Comment: @itoctopus : I have editted my post with query now. I assure that the query is correct. However, I admit there is a scope of query optimization to reduce the time.